# Stable Speech to text apis (Support Arabic) for commercial using?

Tags: api, ibm-cloud, speech-to-text, ibm-watson, google-speech-api

I am searching for a stable Speech to text Apis that support Arabic language to use in a commercial project .
i have below choices :

1. According to [chromium](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/api-keys) that there is no quota for google speech to text apis anymore.

[image]

2. IBM BlueMix Speech to text apis ,after trying the APIs the results wasn't accurate as expected because the input speech is an Egyptian not native Arabic.

Are there any official APIs that support Arabic (Egypt) ?!.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Google Next conference](http://techcrunch.com/2016/03/23/google-opens-access-to-its-speech-recognition-api-going-head-to-head-with-nuance/) on last Wednesday 23-3-2016 they opened their Speech to text Apis for public using with supporting of 80 language .